How to get 2 decimal places without rounding up the number in robot framework?
I am trying to only use 2 decimals places of a number without rounding off.
For example. 1.027 should give after removing the last digit as 1.02

${result}=  Evaluate  "%.2f" % 1.027
${result} =  1.03  #but I would like it to be 1.02


Does this answer your question? How do I round number from 15 digits after decimal point to 6 in robot framework?

Thanks @Luuk, I have checked that already. It does round off to the next digit too, so no it did not answer my question unfortunately.

Below code is currently working for me:
*** Settings ***
Documentation

*** Variables ***
${MYNUMBER1}        1.329999999
${MYNUMBER2}        1.027

*** Test Cases ***
Get Exact Two Decimal Number
    ${result1}         Evaluate  math.floor(${MYNUMBER1} * 100) / 100    modules=math
    Log To Console     My first two decimal exact number is ${result1}!
    ${result2}         Evaluate  math.floor(${MYNUMBER2} * 100) / 100    modules=math
    Log To Console     My second two decimal exact number is ${result2}!

Output is:
==============================================================================
Testdemo6
==============================================================================
Get Two Decimal Number                                                
..My first two decimal exact number is 1.32!
..My second two decimal exact number is 1.02!
Get Two Decimal Number                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testdemo6                                                             | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Development\robot-scripts\Test_Test\results\output.xml
Log:     C:\Development\robot-scripts\Test_Test\results\log.html
Report:  C:\Development\robot-scripts\Test_Test\results\report.html

Hopefully this helps.

Thank you @Pramesh for your quick response, your answered helped. I really appreciate it.
